# The end of the body of the sql stored procecdure (where is it?)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) is giving the following syntax and explanation:

```
{ [ BEGIN ] sql_statement [;] [ ...n ] [ END ] }
```

> One or more Transact-SQL statements comprising the body of the
>   procedure. You can use the optional BEGIN and END keywords to enclose
>   the statements. For information, see the Best Practices, General
>   Remarks, and Limitations and Restrictions sections that follow.

Essentially this is a sequence of SQL statements that ends nobody knows where if there is no BEGIN/END pair. BEGIN/END block is essentially a statement. Can procedure body consist of two sequential BEGIN/END blocks? (Most likely no, but I do not see it written anywhere.) When there is no BEGIN/END pair parser can decide that procedure ended on any top-level SQL-statement. Where is the catch?

Remarks and limitations section are not very helpful either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, two `BEGIN`/`END` pairs can form the body of a single stored procedure:

```
create procedure P
as
begin
    select 1 as A
end
begin
    select 2 as B
end
```

Creates a single stored procedure that produces two result sets.

The actual end of a stored procedure is the end of the *batch*. This is either the entire body of the query you've sent to the server or, if you're using certain client tools (e.g. SSMS), it will automatically split its submissions into batches based on the [`GO` command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx):

> Signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

The clue that everything is batch based is actually the first sentence is the [Limitations and Restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx#Limitations%20and%20Restrictions) section that you already linked to:

> The CREATE PROCEDURE statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

Logically, this implies that the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement consumes the *entire* contents of the batch.

Comment: Hm, it looks that I cannot send several `CREATE POC` statements in one batch not from SSMS at all??? Ex if I am using ODBC?

Comment: @Buran - one batch == one stored procedure, as is hopefully clear from the links/quotes I've edited in.

Comment: This is not directly related, nevertheless. I was thinking that I it is possible to script all database objects (whatever) into a big SQL file and then execute this file from ex my ODBC application to recreate everything say on another server. It looks that this is not possible at all. Right?

Comment: @Buran - it's doable if you include `GO`s between each item that needs to be in separate batches (easiest, just insert them between each object irrespective of whether it's required), and then you need to do the same job that the client tools do - find the `GO`s, split the text into batches based on that and submit each batch individually. Unfortunately, that does need parsing.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I am new to databases and kind of expecting that tricks that you have described should have been implemented already (and long ago). And that I just have no idea they are existing.